# Different approaches to $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sqrt {(n+a)(n+b)}-n\right)=\frac {a+b}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I've collected all the approaches, regarding the popular limit below:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\sqrt {(n+a)(n+b)}-n\right)=\frac {a+b}{2}$$

Here $a,b\in\Bbb R$.

1. Using the [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)
2. Using the [Conjugates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_(square_roots)) (square roots)
3. Using the definition of [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative)
4. Using [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)
5. Using [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) with the [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

I was just wondering.  Can we still add another method to the list?  Could you please share your methods that are still not on the list? Methods that do not rely on prior knowledge of the value of the limit are preferred.

Comment: I thought these links would lead to examples of this being proven with the stated methods, not Wikipedia articles defining the terms. It might be more helpful to at least further sketch out how one would use these methods to arrive at a proof.

Comment: I just wanted to say what @TheoBendit said. Also, do you require that new method to not use any of the theorems and defintions you mentioned?

Comment: @donaastor yes exactly. We want approaches that don't use the methods in the list.

Comment: I have done something about calculating the limit, but it assumes that the limit exists. With that "help" I succesfully avoided any use of any term you mentioned. Does that even satisfy your question? In other words, do you expect us to also answer whether or not the limit exists at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a "different" method, though it's just being different for the sake of being different.

Let's take a quadratic in $x$, with rational coefficients, that has $\sqrt{(n + a)(n + b)} - n$ as a solution. We'll choose it to be monic (why not). The coefficient of $x$ looks like it should be $2n$, which leads the constant term to be $(n + a)(n + b) - n^2 = an + bn + ab$. That is, our polynomial (which we'll index by $n$) will be
$$p_n(x) = x^2 - 2nx + (an + bn + ab).$$
Then $x_n := \sqrt{(n + a)(n + b)} - n$ is the unique positive root of $p_n(x)$.

Note first that $x_n$ is bounded above, as
$$x_n \le \sqrt{(n + \max\{a, b\})(n + \max\{a, b\})} - n = \max\{a, b\}.$$

Rearranging $p_n(x)$ to collect the $n$s, we get
$$p_n(x) = x^2 - 2n\left(x - \frac{a + b}{2}\right) + ab.$$
Note the "naturally" occurring instance of $\frac{a + b}{2}$. Now, $p_n(x_n) = 0$ for all $n$, and so
$$x_n - \frac{a + b}{2} = \frac{x_n^2 + ab}{2n}.$$
The numerator on the right hand side is bounded, and multiplied to the null-convergent sequence $\frac{1}{2n}$, which makes $x_n - \frac{a + b}{2}$ null-convergent. Hence $x_n \to \frac{a + b}{2}$.

Comment: Isn't the last step in your solution a form of the Squeeze theorem?

Comment: @donaastor Yeah, sort of. It can be proven in other ways (e.g. the contrapositive, which is sort of how I had it before my edit).

Comment: @donaastor Actually, reading your answer, my answer was pretty similar in spirit to yours. I just retweaked my version of the "... exists if and only if $\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}-n-\frac{a+b}{2}\rightarrow0$ when $n \to \infty$" step so that it came out a little more direct.

Comment: I know. I even didn't answer the OP's question fully. That's why I wonder if we can avoid Squeeze theorem at all. I can't think of any theorem that results in "this sequence converges" that doesn't have "this other sequence converges" among its conditions. That is how I define "looks like Squeeze theorem". But this thing I used can only calculate the limit, it can't prove it exists. Yeah, btw, my method can kind of avoid Squeeze theorem by saying if (that big thing) doesn't converge to 0 then the limit doesn't exist. But it's again suspicious...

Comment: @donaastor Avoiding using a theorem is, as I'm sure I don't have to tell you, a wishy-washy, ill-defined concept. We never made mention of the squeeze theorem, so by one standard, we avoided it. We, instead, used corollaries of the squeeze theorem, by which I mean, results that are commonly proven by referencing the squeeze theorem. They can be proven in other ways, but does this *really* avoid the use of squeeze theorem?

Comment: @donaastor Before we go down that road, remember how fundamental squeeze theorem really is. It's almost the very definition of a limit (which, obviously it isn't, due to circularity). But, the process for proving most limits (unless they're basically linear polynomials) is to make estimations that essentially amount to finding an easier upper and lower bound that we can more easily prove approach the limit in question (e.g. in proving $x^2\to1$ as $x\to1$, you'll need to locally "bound" the $x+1$ term around $x=1$, showing $0\le x^2-1\le2(x-1)$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $1$).

Comment: @donaastor If we exclude results that use squeeze theorem at some point in their proof, then we exclude almost everything. We exclude L'Hopital's rule and the big O notation proof *at least*. If you're not careful about where you draw the lines, avoiding squeeze theorem, or its spirit, will lock you out of most of the theory of limits.

Comment: I completely agree. The resolution of the OP's question really consists of two parts at both of which we need to surprise ourselves when finding a solution. The first part is to define our concept of "new method", then explain why it is useful to use exactly that method and, of course, provide a solution that uses that method. Now, as you said, if we define it as that we shouldn't recall the Squeeze theorem ever, even in the proofs of other theorems we did recall, then there are two problem, just as you said: Firstly, we can rewrite every use of Squeeze theorem to make it not be called and...

Comment: ...and secondly, we can just allow for proof of other theorems to use the Squeeze theorem. So that's how we didn't even pass the first step in solving the OP's question. We fail to justify how and why our new methods differ, how they generalize and why they are useful to know.

Comment: So my suggestion would be sort of another well-known theorem, which is sufficiently different from the Squeeze theorem in sense that we can rarely easily substitute the use of one with the use of the other. That's why I would exclude the technique of these null-convergent series. You can always make it look like a squeeze theorem, and you can always unpack the squeeze theorem and reduce it to a story about null-convergent series. That is the spirit yuo talk about. So my suggestion is to find another well-known and powerful theorem (which may use the squeeze theorem in its proof) but that...

Comment: ...can't be substituted with Squeeze theorem. Then we need to show that it is useful and general (hence the "well-known" and "powerful" adjectives). My attempt was to use that limit and continuous functions commute, but it didn't solve OP's question fully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141374/discussion-between-donaastor-and-theo-bendit).

Answer (score 1):

Let $a+b=p,\;ab=q$, where $p^2-4q\geqslant 0$, then we have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt {n^2+pn+q}-n$$

First, we observe for all $n>|p|+\sqrt {|q|}$ the following inequality holds:

$$\begin{align}0&\leqslant -n+ \sqrt {n^2+pn+q}\\
&\leqslant -n+\sqrt {\left(n+\frac {p}{2}\right)^2-\frac {\Delta_n}{4}}\\
&\leqslant \frac{|p|}{2}\end{align}$$

Then, define the function $\omega:\mathbb R_{>|p|+\sqrt {|q|}}\longrightarrow \mathbb R_{\geqslant 0}$, where $\omega (n):=\sqrt {n^2+pn+q}-n$ we have:

$$\begin{align}&\sqrt {n^2+pn+q}=\omega (n)+n\\ 
\implies &pn+q=\omega^2(n)+2n\omega (n) \\
\implies &\frac {\omega^2(n)-q}{n}=p-2\omega(n)\end{align}$$

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac {\omega^2(n)-q}{n}=0$, this leads to:

$$\begin{align}&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(p-2\omega(n)\right)=0\\
\implies &\lim_{n\to\infty}\omega (n)=\frac p2=\frac {a+b}{2}\thinspace \thinspace \thinspace \thinspace \thinspace \thinspace \thinspace \thinspace \blacksquare \end{align}$$

Comment: How do we know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\omega^2(n)-q}{n}=0$?

Comment: @Donaastor $\omega(n)$ is bounded.  This can be rigorously construct using epsilon-delta definition.  That is possible

Comment: Alright, so it is the implication null-convergent multiplied by bounded is still null-convergent. Similarly to @TheoBendit 's solution, it resembles the Squeeze theorem. I just doubt that some form of Squeeze theorem can be avoided.

Comment: @donaastor Note that, the epsilon-delta definition is ready for help, but the proof of the Squeeze also uses epsilon -delta.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this method earns a place of a new and unrelated method. You can use the fact that the limit commutes with continuous functions. That is, if $f$ is a continuous function and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n$ exists then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)=f(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n)$. Specifically, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)$ exists. We will choose $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ and $x\mapsto x^2$ whose domains and codomains are positive real numbers. That means we assume $a>0$ and $b>0$. I will come back to this later. So now we have that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Big(\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}-n\Big)$$
exists iff
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Big(\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}-n\Big)^2$$
exists. This limit
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Big(\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}-n\Big)^2=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Big((n+a)(n+b)+n^2-2n\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}\Big)=$$
$$=2\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Big(n^2+n\Big(\frac{a+b}{2}\Big)+\frac{ab}{2}
-n\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}\Big)=$$
$$=ab+2\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Big(n^2-n\Big(\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}-\frac{a+b}{2}\Big)\Big)=$$
$$=ab-2\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Big(n\Big(\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}-n-\frac{a+b}{2}\Big)\Big)$$
exists only if $\sqrt{(n+a)(n+b)}-n-\frac{a+b}{2}\rightarrow0$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$. In other words, if the limit you are asking for exists then it must be equal to $\frac{a+b}{2}$. Now if $a$ or $b$ were negative, you could substitute $n+m$ instead of $n$, where $m=\lceil1-\min\{a,b\}\rceil$ and work it out the same way.

The only thing that remains to be shown is that the limit actually exists. That I will not do here, because I think this method is interesting on its own.